# Ubuntu freezes while copying files and sometimes at country selection

Tags: 18.04

How much time does it take to copy files while installing Ubuntu...cuz Everytime I try to install Ubuntu it freezes and i have tried it with different USBs and different ISO file,
But no use 
Before this, it gives an error stating cannot match 
/target/bin/busybox in hard drive , can u please help me.

Comment: We do not know your connection speed.

Comment: I don't use net connection,doest it play a role??